# android Jetpcak Compose How to use Jetpack Navigation to navigate from a login page to the home page reasonably？

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuL3G.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggGQb.png).
After I jumped from the login page to the home page, I repeatedly clicked the bottom navigation bar button HomeView and AdminView to stack repeatedly. I needed to return multiple times to exit the application.

I'm hoping for a reasonable way to jump from the login page to the main page.

Comment: You need to optimize the BottomNavigation backstack efficiently so that it replaces the existing entry check my blog https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-bottom-navigation-with-scaffold-material3-717e28ccc811

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

you should check documentation

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

navController.navigate(your-way)  // it is in your onClick function.



NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = start-way 
    ) {
        composable(route = route-way) {
//            HomeScreen()
        }
```